# Smallest number to be made in one way

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Take the numbers 1,3,4,6,9,10. We can make other numbers using these numbers and the operations +,-,*,/. E.g. we can make 244 with:

```
10 * 3 = 30
30 - 6 = 24
9 + 1 = 10
24 * 10 = 240
240 + 4 = 244
```

In this case there is more than one way to do it. For example,

```
3 + 1 = 4
10 * 6 * 4 = 240
240 + 4 = 244
```

This second solution also doesn't use all the given numbers.

There is only one way to make 713, that is:

```
9 * 6 = 54
54 - 3 = 51
10 + 4 = 14
51 * 14 = 714
714 - 1 = 713
```

What is the smallest positive integer that can be made in exactly one way and also requires using each one of 1,3,4,6,9,10? You can use each number exactly once.

As an example, 10 is no good as a target number as you can make it just using the number 10.

Comment: Is this [no-computers]?

Comment: @bobble you can use a computer if you prefer.

Comment: What is a different way ?  Is 1/(3/6) differnt from 6/3/1 ?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: @Rubio it hasn't been given yet

Answer (score 4):

the answer that I found is

> 695

with

> $ 9+3 = 12$

> $ 12*10 = 120$

> $ 120-4 = 116$

> $ 116*6=696$

> $696-1=695$

I wrote a program and all other numbers below 695 has multiple answers.

Comment: 4 + 3 = 7
10 * 9 * 7 = 630
630 - 1 = 629
629 + 6 = 635


9 * 6 = 54
54 + 4 = 58
10 + 1 = 11
58 * 11 = 638
638 - 3 = 635

Comment: @Simd editted again :)

Comment: What about 691?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with. I'll keep playing around ;^)

> 4 * 3 = 12
> 12 / 6 = 2
> 2 * 10 = 20
> 20 - 9 = 11
> 11 - 1 = **10**

Incidentally, is there a definitive correct answer? I.e. one you generated with an alogrithm beforehand.

Comment: Another way is $(10+9+1+6+4)/3$

Comment: Good one - I'll admit a I'm a bit fuzzy on the rules, was going by OP's lead.

Comment: You can make 10 just using the number 10 as well so this isn’t allowed. I added a clarification.

Comment: @Simd but using just the number 10 isn't using all numbers exactly once? So for the purpose of the condition "exactly one way", we are also including those which don't use all numbers?

Comment: @justhalf Yes. I will try to make it clearer in the question.